# How to track deployment and commits of multiple repositories in a single Bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: jira, bitbucket-pipelines

We host a project's source code on Bitbucket, in multiple repositories, one for the backend, one from the frontend, and one for server configuration and deployment.

The deployment is done with a Bitbucket custom pipeline hosted in the latter repository (where "custom" means triggered manually or by a scheduler, not by pushing to branch). In the pipeline, we clone the other repositories (using an SSH key for authentication), build Docker images, push them to a Docker repository, and then trigger the deployment on the server.

This is all working well, except for how it's tracked in Bitbucket and Jira. In Bitbucket, in the pipelines overview, it shows the latest commit that was deployed by a pipeline run. However, since the pipeline is in the config repository, this will only show commits of the config repository. Since the config rarely changes, most of our commits are in the backend and frontend repositories, so this "latest commit" rarely represents the latest change that was deployed.

Similarly, and more annoyingly, when [connecting Jira with Bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/integrate-jira-and-pipelines/), Jira only associates commits in the config repository with a deployment. All the interesting work done in the backend and frontend repositories isn't seen.

Is there away to tell Bitbucket that multiple repositories are involved in a pipeline deploy? I believe this is currently not possible, so this would have to be a feature request for Atlassian.

Does anybody know of a workaround? I was thinking, maybe having the backend and frontend repos as git submodules of the config repo might work? Git submodules scare me, so I don't want to try only to find out that Bitbucket/Jira would not see the commits/issues in the submodules anyway.

Another workaround could be to push a dummy commit with a commit message that summarizes all commits done in all repos. That commit would have to be already pushed to the config repo when the pipeline is started, so that would maybe have to be done in a separate pipeline: the first pipeline pushes the summary commit and then triggers the second pipeline for the actual deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything, all software components plus configuration and infrastructure, together in a monorepository.

So as to push such a big change in historically independent repositories, it is worth to use the [`--allow-unrelated-histories`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories) option for the git-merge command so as not to loose each git history.

Otherwise, yes, use git submodules in a parent repo and track submodules refs updates as meaningful commits. If that scares you, you should really not be splitting your code in multiple repos.

Comment: Putting everything in a monorepo would be too big of a change. Our current setup works well for development and deployment, only in Bitbucket and Jira it isn't tracked correctly. Git submodules might be a way to go, could you elaborate on "track submodules refs updates as meaningful commits", how do I do that? Will Bitbucket see the commits in the submodules?

Comment: It looks to me like submodules need to be manually updated in the pipeline with `git submodule update --init --recursive`, according to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-git-submodules-in-bitbucket-pipelines). Doing it this way, Bitbucket would not see the commits. That would be basically the same as we do it now, just with `git submodule update` instead of `git clone` in the first step of the pipeline. Bummer.

Comment: In the commit where you update the submodules, the message could be a squash for all the submodule commit messages being updated. I know no automated way to do that, it deserves an in-depth study. My answer is an advice to use monorepos instead. (I am done splitting software in repos that will evolve together, my live is much easier now) You can always workout the submodule approach and answer your question yourself, but see my updated answer.

Comment: The problem with the commit message is that it would be pushed within the first step of the pipeline. By that time, Bitbucket doesn't see it as the commit that triggered the pipeline. I guess, it's currently only possible with two pipelines, one to update/clone and push a commit message and a second to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we have a bash script collects and pushes an issue summary to the pipeline repository.

The scripts grep the commit messages since the last release (git tag):

```bash
issues_pattern='[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]+'
if [[ "$environment" == "production" ]]; then
  issue_summary=
  for repository in $repositories; do
    last_tag="$(git -C ../"$repository" describe --tags --abbrev=0 "$branch")"
    issues="$(git -C ../"$repository" log --pretty=format:%s "$last_tag".."$branch"\
     | grep -E "$issues_pattern"\
     | sort --version-sort\
     | uniq\
     || echo -n)"
    if [[ -n "$issues" ]]; then
      issue_summary="$issue_summary\n$repository:\n$issues\n"
    fi
  done
  if [[ -n "$issue_summary" ]]; then
    issue_summary="Issue summary${version:+ for }${version:-}\n$issue_summary"
    echo -e "$issue_summary"
    if prompt "Do you want to commit and push the above issue summary to master?"; then
      git switch master
      git commit --allow-empty --message "$(echo -e "$issue_summary")"
      git push "$(git remote)"
      git switch -
    fi
  fi
fi
```

The main disadvantage of doing it this way, is that we need to deploy with the script, it does not work from the Bitbucket UI.